# Shell Script for jar releases

Tags: java, spring, shell, unix, classpath

I did a `java` project using `spring framework`. The project uses a properties file to read in jdbc properties. It also uses log4j properties file where I made logging configurations.

How do I refer to these properties file in a shell script and run the .jar file. Can someone please also suggest a good directory structure for scripts, jar file, logs, properties file etc for this instance ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest providing configuration files on classpath like:

```
java -server -cp "${libPath}:${configurationPath}:${HOME}/somethingInteresting" -Dlog4j.configurationFile=${configurationPath}/log4j2.xml ...
```

And the following structure:

```
|-- bin
|   |-- start.sh
|   `-- stop.sh
|-- config
|   |-- Dev
|   |   |-- config.properties
|   |   `-- log4j2.xml
|   |-- Test
|   |   |-- config.properties
|   |   `-- log4j2.xml
|   |-- QA
|   |   |-- config.properties
|   |   `-- log4j2.xml
|   |-- Prod
|   |   |-- config.properties
|   |   `-- log4j2.xml
|-- lib
|   |-- log4j-1.2-api-2.0-beta9.jar
|   |-- log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar
|   |-- log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar
|   |-- slf4j-api-1.6.6.jar
|   |-- spring-aop-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
|   |-- spring-beans-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
|   |-- spring-context-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
|   |-- spring-core-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar
|-- logs
|   |-- appLog.log
|   |-- appLog.errors.log
```